# Changing the opacity of background color continously without using an image

Tags: css

I have built a div element and gave the background color green.Then,I wanted to change the color's opacity until it is white, from top to bottom. The darkest green will be top and lightest color which is white will be the bottom of it. Is there any way to do that with css,without creating an image for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 to generate background gradients (via the background-image element) BUT it's not uniformly supported across browsers.

You'd be looking at code like this:

```
  background-color: #108B00; /* Fallback solid color */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #108B00, #FFFFFF); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #108B00, #FFFFFF); /* FF3.6 */
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #108B00, #FFFFFF); /* IE10 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #108B00, #FFFFFF); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #108B00, #FFFFFF);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#108B00', EndColorStr='#FFFFFF'); /* IE6–IE9 */
```